# Calling different functions upon clicking button in angular 6

Tags: angular

Hey may i know that if there is any possibility in angular that we can call different different functions upon clicking the same button like on first click i wanna call  function A and then on second click i wanna call function B .
If yes? then pls help

```
<button (click)="onclick()" type="button">Save </button?
```

and then after clicking for the first time i want to call function A

```
functionA()
{
}
```

and then on second click functionB

```
functionB()
{
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a property in your component and have logic to increment on click.  Please see below...

```
export class MyComponent {
  constructor() {}
  private buttonCounter:number = 0;

  click() {
  this.buttonCounter++;
  switch this.buttonCounter {
    case 1:
      functionA();
      break;
   case 2:
     functionB();
     break;
  default:
    break;


  }



  }
```

Answer (score 0):

One-liner...

`<button (click)="!alreadyClicked ? functionA() : functionB(); alreadyClicked = true">Save</button>`

Function A will be hit first. Function B will be hit each time after.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say on first click you want to call function_A. on second click function_B, and so on.

```
    clicks = (function() {
    var first = true;
    var second = true;
    return function() {
      if(first == true && second == true){
        this.function_A();
        second = false;
        first = false;} else if(first == false && second == false){
          this.function_B();
          first = true;
          second = false;} else if(first==true && second==false){
            this.function_C();
            first = false;
            second = true;
          }
          else{
            this.function_D();
            first = true;
            second = true;
          }

    }
  })();




function_A() {
   "do something";
  };

function_B() {
   "do something";
  };

function_C() {
   "do something";
  };

function_D() {
   "do something";
  };
```

and in HTML set the "(click) = clicks()" under button property.

I hope this will work.

Comment: This is really not the "typescript" way of doing things. You should go with the component property like @Paul suggested

Comment: @SeaBiscuit Actually I'm a beginner in this field. But I tried what paul suggested. didn't work in my case.